# MUI: button within a MenuItem: When I click the button without clicking the MenuItem?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI's [Menu / MenuItem](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/menu-item/) to build a menu of missions / tasks like this screenshot:

[image]

The `MenuItem` is clickable:

```
// ... other code

        <MenuItem 
          value={mission.issueIdentifierId}
          sx={{px: 0.5}}
          onClick={() => handleMenuItemClick(mission.issueIdentifierId)}
        >
          <UploadMissionCard mission={mission} />
        </MenuItem>

// ... other code
```

and when it is clicked, a modal window will pop up to show the detail info.

Now, within the `MenuItem`, there is the `UploadMissionCard` component, and in some cases, the `UploadMissionCard` would contain a MUI Button called `Abort`. On clicking the button, a different warning modal window will pop up.

However, when I click the button, the clicking action propagates to the `menuItem` as well and the `menuItem` is also clicked. So both modal window are opened.

In MUI, how can I put a `Button` inside a `MenuItem` and stop the clicking action on the button from passing on to the parent `MenuItem`?

Comment: so can't we stop the `propogation` like `event.stopPropagation()` ?

Comment: @KcH  You are right. Thank you very much. Lesson learnt today :)

Answer (score 2):

Call stopPropagation method on button click event

```
<button onClick={(event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
}}></button>
```